# Pandas data_range to epoch in miliseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unix-timestamp, epoch

I am generating a data range using pandas and after transforming to epoch, however I realized that the `mktime` function is given me my local timezone and not UTC.

How do I get an list of dates in UTC epoch (milliseconds)?

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2022', end='10/1/2022',
                      freq='M', tz='UTC').strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").tolist()

print(dates)

list_epoch=[]

for i in dates:
    epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")))*1000
    list_epoch.append(epoch)

print(list_epoch)
```

Comment: datetime data type uses Unix time internally, so you can directly convert to a numeric representation using `astype`. By doing that, you bypass the conversion to string (`strftime`), back to datetime (`strptime`), then to numeric (`mktime`) and instead get directly to where you want to be.

Comment: as to why your code is buggy (uses local time): your parsing directive `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"`uses a literal Z. By that, you basically ignore the fact that it's UTC. You should have used `%z` instead. The resulting datetime object is [naive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects), which means that Python will treat it as *local time*. Using `%z` to parse the Z will give you an aware datetime object in contrast, which "knows" it's UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the date_range to integer nanoseconds and divide by 1e6 to get milliseconds.

```py
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2022', end='10/1/2022',
                      freq='M', tz='UTC') # do not use strftime here

unixmilli = dates.astype(int) / 1e6
```

```
unixmilli
Float64Index([1643587200000.0, 1646006400000.0, 1648684800000.0,
              1651276800000.0, 1653955200000.0, 1656547200000.0,
              1659225600000.0, 1661904000000.0, 1664496000000.0],
             dtype='float64')
```

now you could also convert to list:

```
unixmilli.to_list()
[1643587200000.0,
 1646006400000.0,
 1648684800000.0,
 1651276800000.0,
 1653955200000.0,
 1656547200000.0,
 1659225600000.0,
 1661904000000.0,
 1664496000000.0]
```